# RealTime chart in recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have a function where the data comes in random order and not in one block. This is my array:

```
this.props.data = [
{date: "07", visitors: 0},
{date: "08", visitors: 8},
{date: "09", visitors: 14},
{date: "10", visitors: 17},
{date: "11", visitors: 23},
{date: "12", visitors: 31},
{date: "13", visitors: 40}]
```

And the following chart code

```
<LineChart data={this.props.data}>
  <XAxis dataKey='date' label={{ value: "Horas", position: "insideBottom", dy: 10} } />
  <YAxis label={{ value: 'Visitantes', angle: -90, position: 'insideLeft' }}/>
  <Tooltip/>
  <Line type="monotone" dataKey="visitors" stroke="#001529" activeDot={{r: 5}}/>
</LineChart>
```

The issue is, my highest visitors value is lower on the chart than the first. (Reminder: He is 5 times greater than the first one).
[image: Lowest value]

[image: Highest value]

There is some problem inside my code? Or is this an issue of recharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/tkeffer/pen/LrVdzN?editors=1111)

```
const {LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, Tooltip} = Recharts;

const mydata = [
{date: "07", visitors: 0},
{date: "08", visitors: 8},
{date: "09", visitors: 14},
{date: "10", visitors: 17},
{date: "11", visitors: 23},
{date: "12", visitors: 31},
{date: "13", visitors: 40}]

const SimpleLineChart = function() {
    return (
    <LineChart data={mydata} width={600} height={400} margin={{ top: 50, bottom: 50, left:50, right:50}}>
      <XAxis dataKey='date'/>
      <YAxis label='Visitantes'/>
      <Line type="monotone" dataKey="visitors" stroke="#001529" activeDot={{r: 5}}/>
      <Tooltip/>
    </LineChart>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <SimpleLineChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```